# scrapy recursive scrape website

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to write a scraper that visits all subpages of the initial page.

The example website is: **pydro.com**
So it should for example also extract **pydro.com/impressum** and save it as an html file on my hard drive.

The code I wrote:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from finalproject.items import FinalprojectItem


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "projects"  # Spider name
    allowed_domains = ["pydro.com"]  # Which (sub-)domains shall be scraped?
    start_urls = ["https://pydro.com/"]  # Start with this one
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]  # Follow any link scrapy finds (that is allowed).

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('Got a response from %s.' % response.url)
        self.logger.info('Hi this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        page = response.url.split('.com/')[-1]
        filename = 'pydro.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

When I run my spider the output is only `pydro.html`.

I think I need to adjust my filename, that i get the subpage. Or do I need a for loop?

EDIT1:
I edited the code to get all html pages. But when I want to run the script on another website I get an error called:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'otego-https://www.otego.de/de/jobs.php'
```

Thats the script I run:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "otego" #Spider name
    allowed_domains = ["otego.de"] # Which (sub-)domains shall be scraped?
    start_urls = ["https://www.otego.de/en/index.php"] # Start with this one
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)] # Follow any link scrapy finds (that is allowed).

def parse_item(self, response):
    print('Got a response from %s.' % response.url)
    self.logger.info('Hi this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    page = response.url
    filename = 'otego-%s' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a recursive scraping.
A 'sub-page' is simply another page whose url is obtained from a 'previous' page. You must make a second request to the sub-page (its url should be in the variable sel) and use xpath on the (2nd) response.

[How to recursively crawl subpages with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293662/how-to-recursively-crawl-subpages-with-scrapy)

Comment: well, I thought when I use the CrawlSpider, i crawl recursively. This is why I added the rule i guess? I adjusted the code a little bit:

page = response.url.split('.com/')[-1]
        filename = 'pydro-%s.html' % page

I saw that the url because every url ends with .com/ I split it after the .com/ and paste whats left behind the filename. Now I get every html on my hard drive. Now I want to apply it to another website. Doesn't work....